# Review stats and history pages URL update to a new review item

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

I encountered this bug on accident when I refreshed twice quickly, but apparently it's happening consistently:

1. open a review queue's stats page. For example, [First answers' stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/stats)
2. observe the URL/address bar
3. wait for the page to load
4. the URL changes from `https://stackoverflow.com/review/<queue>/stats` to `https://stackoverflow.com/review/<queue>/<task id>`

I'm not sure if it's a desired behavior, but it's for sure an unexpected one. I used the refresh to get back the badge progress count after the review and suddenly got redirected to a new review item which was just weird.

Comment: Also happens on the [history page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/history).

Comment: Reported at meta.stackexchange in  [Navigating to review /stats and /history causes the URL to change to a specific review item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369889/navigating-to-review-stats-and-history-causes-the-url-to-change-to-a-specific)

Comment: Are you still able to reproduce this? I'm not able to on my end. I wonder if this has been resolved? The [original Stack Exchange thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369889/navigating-to-review-stats-and-history-causes-the-url-to-change-to-a-specific) doesn't indicate that the issue has been fixed.

Comment: @JeremyCaney yes, still broken.

Comment: Hi there - is this still happening? We shipped an unrelated fix recently that I think should coincidentally fix this as well - we were calling `NextTask()` on each tab instead of only on the task tab.

Comment: @kristinalustig yes, it seems to be fixed - given that you fixed the `NextTask` call on tabs not related to reviewing a new task specifically, it should have fixed this one too. At least it does not reproduce for me.

Comment: Great - that's what I hoped/figured! I'll mark this as well as the other report as completed, please just let me know if you or anyone is still experiencing and I'll take another look.

Comment: @kristinalustig sure, for now, seems to be working fine as expected on a clean browser (no userscripts, no extensions, etc) - thanks for fixing this

Comment: @kristinalustig I can also confirm it's been fixed. Thanks! :)